# Can I assume the continum hypothesis in a proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, cardinals, infinity

I am showing that the cantor ternary set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$

I want to use the fact that it is uncountably infinite and a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. ($|N| < |C| \leq \mathbb{R}$)

If I assume the continum hypothesis, the proof is done, but can I really do this? Is it a valid proof?

Notes:

The continum hypothesis:
There is no set whose cardinality is strictly between that of the integers and the real numbers.

Definition of Cantor Ternary Set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

Comment: I don't see how you show it's uncountably infinite without showing it has the same size as R.

Comment: Following @mercio's comment, do you really have a proof that $|C|>|N|$ without showing $|C|=|R|$? If you do, could you explain how you do this?

Comment: @mercio I'm not sure this is what the OP did (in fact, I suspect it's not) but here's a proof that the Cantor set is uncountable without using a bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ - you just do the closed intervals argument: given an enumeration $\alpha_i$ of elements of $C$, we define a sequence $A_i$ of decreasing (bounded nonsingleton) closed intervals, each with $\alpha_i\not\in A_i$ and $A_i$ contained in the $i$th stage of the Cantor set. The existence of such a sequence of intervals is easy to prove, as is the fact that the intersection of the $A_i$s is nonempty and is in the Cantor set.

Comment: (cont'd) Of course, it's not hard to go from this to a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$, but technically it's not necessary.

Comment: Chances are good that however you're showing $C$ to be uncountable, actually shows it to have the same size as $\Bbb R$. Bear in mind that it's not so easy to define a subset of $\Bbb R$ having size $\aleph_1$ (unless CH, lol).

Comment: @mercio Cantor set is a nonempty perfect set, and any  nonempty perfect set in $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, I am not sure how this statement generalizes and for what kind of metric spaces it does.
I am aware there are other ways using the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, but just wanted to know how we can proceed that way

Comment: @Quintic  I don't think it's right what you are saying.  I believe the independence of the CH with the ZF axioms is a completely different issue from Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Answer (score 4):

You may prove it under the continuum hypothesis, but in your case CH in unnecessary. You can construct a explicit bijection $f$ between the Cantor set and $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$, namely
$$n\in f(x)\iff \text{$n$th digit of tenary expansion of $x$ after dot is 2}$$
(The tenary expansion of $x$ may not be unique, if $x$ is rational. In that case, choose the expansion which contains no 1. Such representation is unique.)

If possible, you should avoid using the continuum hypothesis. Our usual mathematics does not assume the continuum hypothesis and there are lot of (philosophical) disputes whether the continuum hypothesis is 'correct' axiom or not. 
If you prove something under continuum hypothesis, people who does not accept the continuum hypothesis (or even accept the axiom contradicted with the CH) would not accept your result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the continuum hypothesis is not provable or disprovable you can complete the set theory with CH or it's negation and get a new axiom system. Within that (first) system it's valid to use CH in a proof as it's a system where CH is an axiom.

Most mathematicians are only concerned with the standard ZFC set theory (including the axiom of choice). Therefore a statement with proof requiring CH would not concern most, even if you can transform the statement without needing to add the axiom (for example "If CH holds then the Cantor set has the same cardinality os $\mathbb R$).

So they would not discard it as being invalid (given that you assume CH as an axiom or prerequisite in your statement), they would discard it because it doesn't interrest them.

Your example is a bit bad since you can prove the stament without having to use CH and therefore the proof would probably be discarded anyhow as relying on unrequired assumptions. Most would probably strive to drop as many requirements, making the prerequisite in a theorem as generic as possible

Since the CH is independent of the standard axiom set any concrete set you may have created without using the negation of CH will have the property that it will either be countable or have cardinality of at least $|\mathbb R|$ (or maybe that it's cardinality can't be decided - I would like to see such a set if it can be described). This is because if you could construct a set without using the negation of CH that has cardinality between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ you would have disproved the CH.

So hopefully for any uncountable set you encounter it should be possible to prove that it has cardinality of at least $|\mathbb R|$ without having to use the CH.

Comment: I suspect that his attempt goes as: 1. the Cantor set is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$, so its cardinality is less or equal than $|\Bbb{R}|$. 2. Proving the Cantor set is uncountable: I don't grasp how he proved it but it can be proven the fact that every perfect subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable. From this we can deduce that the cardinality of the Cantor set is greater or equal than $\aleph_1$. If we assuming CH, then we can deduce that the cardinality of the Cantor set is $\aleph_1$ by Cantor-Bernstein.

Comment: @skyking, see my comment to the OP for how one *can* prove that $C$ has cardinality continuum, using CH, without establishing an explicit bijection.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't see how your proof is using the CH. It sounds like more a rather direct proof of the Cantor set being uncountable.

Comment: @skyking Yes - and CH is **exactly** the statement, "Any uncountable set of reals has size continuum."

Comment: @HanulJeon yes that is what I did. I used the fact that every \emph{nonempty} perfect subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable

Comment: @islamfaisal Interestingly, every nonempty perfect subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ is in fact equipotent to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @HanulJeon Indeed, that is true. The ultimate goal of the question is to discuss in practice how the mathematical community would accept proofs based on CH not to prove that $|C| = |\mathbb{R}|$

Comment: @islamfaisal The theorem I said is a consequence of Cantor-Bendixson theorem. As far as I know, Cantor-Bendixson theorem is used to justify the continuum hypothesis, by Cantor. For further information I recommend the article *"Believing the axioms. I"* by Maddy.